# Ignored_column is not working when using grid search in h2o library - Python

Tags: python, debugging, h2o, hyperparameters

The parameter called `ignored_columns` (see [link](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/ignored_columns.html)) helps user to keep a feature that you want to be ignored when building a model.

When I build a simple ML model and analyze the feature importance, I can see that `h2o` ignores the column that I speficied during the training process, which can be observed from the feature importance. As shown below, column `c` is not used during training.

```
import pandas as pd 
import h2o
from h2o.estimators import H2ODeepLearningEstimator
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator

h2o.init()

x = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 4], [5, 1, 6], [15, 2, 0], [25, 5 , 32], 
                  [35, 11 ,89], [45, 15, 1], [55, 34,3], [60, 35,4]], columns = ['a','b','c'])
y = pd.DataFrame([4, 5, 20, 14, 32, 22, 38, 43], columns = ['label'])
hf = h2o.H2OFrame( pd.concat([x,y], axis="columns"))

X = hf.col_names[:-1]   
y = hf.col_names[-1] 

model=  H2ORandomForestEstimator(ignored_columns = ['c'])

model.train(y = y, training_frame=hf)
model.varimp(use_pandas=True)

variable    relative_importance scaled_importance   percentage
0   b   33876.328125    1.000000    0.540893
1   a   28753.998047    0.848793    0.459107
```

However, when I turn on the grid search for the hyper parameter tunning, it does not seem like working.

```
params = {'max_depth': list(range(7, 16)),   'sample_rate': [0.8], }
criteria = {'strategy': 'RandomDiscrete', 'max_models': 4}
grid = H2OGridSearch(model= H2ORandomForestEstimator(ignored_columns = ['c']),
                              search_criteria=criteria,
                              hyper_params=params )

grid.train( y = y, training_frame=hf)
best_model =  grid.get_grid(sort_by='rmse', decreasing=False)[0]
best_model.varimp(use_pandas=True)
    variable    relative_importance scaled_importance   percentage
0   a   33525.109375    1.000000    0.516545
1   b   23314.916016    0.695446    0.359230
2   c   8062.515137 0.240492    0.124225
```